# Вывести все записи, кроме самой первой с наименьшей датой

Tags: sql, postgresql

В таблице появилось очень много дублей, мне необходимо вывести все дублирующиеся записи, кроме самой первой (так скажем оригинальной), что бы потом их вычистить. Самая первая является с наименьшей датой.
Написала следующий скрипт:

```
select date_cr, guid, client_ds from ds_services where rate = '2034723753' and date_cr != (select MIN(date_cr) from s_services) order by date_cr
```

Но по итогу выводит так же все записи с rate = '2034723753', подскажите какое лучше условие тогда прописать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> мне необходимо вывести все дублирующиеся записи, кроме самой первой (так скажем оригинальной), что бы потом их вычистить.

Смысл? чего на них любоваться? надо сразу удалять...

```sql
DELETE t1.*
FROM ds_services t1
JOIN ds_services t2 USING (rate)
WHERE t1.date_cr > t2.date_cr
-- AND t1.rate = 2034723753
-- либо
-- AND t1.rate IN (список значений)
```

Но если прёт вывести - заменить `DELETE t1.*` на `SELECT DISTINCT t1.*` .

Comment: спасибо, изначально мне нужно их действительно выгрузить, что бы произвести определенный анализ для моей курсовой работы. Таких rate действительно много и необходимо для каждого вывести дублирующиеся записи (то есть все кроме первой по дате)

Comment: Ну выводите. Хоть по одному, хоть несколько, хоть все. Всё, что для этого требуется - указано. Если постгресс начнёт ругаться на USING (хотя с чего бы) - замените `USING (rate)`  на `ON t1.rate = t2.rate`.

Answer (score 1):

OFFSET 2 - выборка начнется со второй записи

```
order by date_cr
offset 2;
```

Comment: спасибо, так подойдет если rate только один, а если у меня их несколько и для каждого нужно вывести только дублирующийся записи (все кроме первой по дате)

Comment: у вас ведь запрос явно привязан к конкретному rate (вы укaзываете это в секции where rate = '2034723753'). Или что значит ваш комментарий "если rate только один, а если у меня их несколько"?

Comment: да, я просто уточнила на будущее, так как придется у большого кол-ва rate выводить

Comment: Ну вот, будете менять значение в секции where и запрос будет возвращать записи для конкретного rate.

Comment: а есть возможность в одном запросе использовать несколько rate? where rate in и при этом что бы от каждого выводились только дубли, без первой записи

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобралась)